# How to change all elements of a particular value in r to their length via loops

Tags: r, rstudio

I am having issues modifying my vector in r, such that all the elements are represented as the number of elements.

More specifically, say:

```
z <- c(1,1,2,2,2)
```

What I want to do is create a loop that runs through the entire vector and replaces the 1s with the number of 1s in the vector, and the 2s with the number of 2s in the vector. I want to obtain the following result :

```
z <- c(2,2,3,3,3)
```

I have done the following, which only applies to the 1s, however, it does not apply to the 2s.

```
for (i in 1:length(z)){

  for (k in 1:length(unique(z))){

    if(z==k){z[z==k]<-length(which(z==k))}

    else(z[z==k]<-k)

  }
  print(z)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ave`:

```
> z<- c(1,1,2,2,2)
> z
[1] 1 1 2 2 2
> ave(z, z, FUN = length)
[1] 2 2 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may like to use the table() feature in R to do the counting job...

```
z  <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
t1 <- as.data.frame(table(z))
z  <- t1$Freq[match(z,t1[,1])]
[1] 2 2 3 3 3
```